# Windows 8 won't install on Lenovo E430

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, multi-boot, thinkpad, windows-installation

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E430 with Ubuntu 12.04 installed on it.

Today I downloaded Windows 8 Professional and Windows 8.1 Professional (yes, really, read on) from DreamSpark.  But when I boot from the Win8 CD, it only displays a brick-colored column pattern. When I try to install the Win8.1, it starts but then tells me there is a driver missing.

UPDATE: Win 8 disk is bad and does not boot on any computer.

No CD came with the laptop. There is no option to go on with the installation. It also did not tell me exactly what the missing driver is.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

UPDATE:
It writes, that the missing driver is a media driver - "it may be USB, hard drive or optical drive". I tried to put some drivers I DL-ed from support.lenovo.com on a flash drive and connect it when asked, but nothing changed.

Comment: Might be a busted optical drive... Does the disk (it'll be a DVD not a CD ;) ) boot as expected in another computer?

Comment: I burned those DVDs on this drive and Win 8.1 boots ok, just has a problem finding some driver. So how do you mean "busted" ?

Trying to boot the 8 on another computer now, seems it does not boot. So the DVD may be bad. But still, the 8.1 boots ok

Comment: Well now that you've determined you Win8.0 disk is bad, you should edit out the parts in your question about trying to use it and getting the coloured blocks, as it will only serve to cloud your issue(s) with 8.1.

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft in [KB2755139](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2755139)...

The cause for:

> Load Driver
>
> A media driver your computer needs is missing. This could be a DVD,
>   USB, or Hard disk driver. If you have a CD, DVD, or USB flash drive
>   with the driver on it, please insert it now.
>
> Note: If the installation media for Windows in the DVD drive or on a
>   USB drive, you can safely remove it for this step

is bad install media.

> - The installation DVD is removed during the setup process.
> - A low-quality DVD was used to create the installation DVD.
> - The speed at which the installation DVD was burned was too fast.
> - The DVD drive cannot read the media.
> - The ISO file is corrupted.

Based on what you found about the 8.0 disk you burned not booting in *any* computer, I'd say you need to try and burn these with another optical drive as yours seems to be malfunctioning.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I will try burning it with a lower speed first ( I hope the disk drive is ok ), then on another drive.
Will update then.

Comment: Don't forget @Argentus if this answer was right to mark it as such,  or at least provide feedback 